# How to kill multiple processes

Tags: kill, ps, process-management

to find the PID of the process to kill use :

```
pgrep <process command>
```

I then use the kill command to kill the PID returned by `pgrep <process command>`

```
kill <PID>
```

Can these commands be combined into one so can kill the PID or PID's returned by `pgrep <process command>` ? Or is there a method kill multiple processes by command name ?

Something like : `kill(pgrep <name of process>)`

Comment: Did you try `pkill`? Alternatively, you may want to use `xargs`.

Comment: Note that man pages are also good for stuff like this. Often they not only tell you how to use the command, they also tell you about related commands. In this case, the `pgrep` man page mentions `pkill` all over the place (as the 2 commands come from the same package).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use pkill:

```
pkill httpd
```

You may also want to use process substitution(although this isn't as clear):

```
kill $(pgrep command)
```

And you may want to use `xargs`:

```
pgrep command | xargs kill
```

Comment: I did a similar thing in an answer and it was pointed out to me that I introduced a race condition. The process IDs may be invalidated inbetween the calls to `pgrep` and `kill`. Just use `pkill`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the same thing can also happen between `pkill` getting the process list and actually sending the signal, it's just harder to see in that case.

Comment: I was going to try to compose an answer that looped something like `kill $(ps|head -1)` to avoid the race condition ... but there really isn't a way to avoid it. The process could die at any point in the pipeline.

Comment: Just be careful with pkill because some programs may have more than one instance running and you might not want to kill all of them. Running pgrep first will help as long as another one doesn't start between the time you run pgrep and pkill (race).

Comment: Even a C program can't avoid the race condition, the window will just be smaller. The only way to do it truly atomically would be to add a system call that kills processes by name. But process IDs generally won't be reused very quickly, so the danger is virtually nonexistent.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `killall` as well, e.g.

```
killall firefox
```

to send `SIGTERM` to all `firefox` processes.

Comment: Note that `killall` has different meanings on different unix systems - if you're on a non-Linux system make sure to check the documentation.

Comment: `killall -KILL firefox` can feel _sooo_ rewarding.

Comment: The non-portability of `killall` is why I never use it. Running `killall` on a solaris box for example is disastrous.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use a bash feature and looping over the output.

```
$ for proc in $(pgrep <process command>); do kill $proc; done
```

Comment: I get `kill <no>:failed: operation not permitted`

Comment: Probably you do not have the right permissions or the process does not exists anymore, please refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/1175485/why-operation-not-permitted-when-kill-a-nonexistent-process-and-why-need-to-be-k

Answer (score 0):

You can kill multiple process with array. In this case you can specify options as `$ip`, `$hostname` or something similar.

```
ip=your_ip_address; declare -a arr=$(ps aux|grep tail|grep $ip|awk '{print $2}'); for pid in ${arr[@]}; do kill -9 $pid; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are running scripts, especially in a stacking way, giving process name does not work for me. Thus I am using this simple command:

```
ps -eaf | grep -i script_hint (or whatever condition is) | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15
```